# pycharm notebook shows persian characters as "?????" in pandas data frame loaded with pd.read_sql_query() method

Tags: python, database, oracle

I am trying to run a .sql file on an oracle database and return the output as a pandas data frame (I am working on pycharm notebook).
My code works, but in the returned data frame I have an encoding issue. Persian characters shown as "?????" signs.

I try some ways such as:
1- passing the encoding parameter to the connect() function ...

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=user, password=pass_, dsn=dsn_tns,encoding='utf-8')
```

2- set windows language setting and encoding as 'utf-8' as well as in pycharm settings